# How to disable window effects in 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, window, animations

Recently, I've installed 15.04 on ubuntu. As my system has low RAM, I want to disable window animations on my lapi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Install **Unity Tweak Tool** by running the following in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Start **Unity Tweak Tool** via Dash or run `unity-tweak-tool` in a terminal.
3. In the **Window Manager** section, press the **General** icon.

   [image: General]
4. In the **Animations** section, set **Window Animations** to off.

   [image: Off]