# Disable window content while dragging @ gnome+metacity Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, metacity

How to disable gnome display window content while the window is being moved?

Among many other things, I tried:

`gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory -s -t bool /apps/metacity/general/reduced_resources true`

From here: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?103724-How-to-disable-gnome-showing-window-content-while-moving-window

And I also tried this: [How to disable window effects in 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653870/how-to-disable-window-effects-in-15-04)

Nothing worked.

My configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.4.0-1025-aws 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Metacity 
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Icons: breeze [GTK2/3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal as the user:
`gsettings set org.gnome.metacity reduced-resources true`

works instantly on my metacity 20.04

Comment: Tks! I’ll try soon!

Comment: Can the same be achieved with Gnome Shell?